# Writing Bitmap to external storage (sdcard)

Tags: android, bitmap, android-sdcard

I'm trying to save Bitmap that I have in certain activity to External Storage in a directory that I create for this purpose. The method for saving the image to sdcard (external memory, not external sd) is in a different class (and different package) so I assumed I will need the context, but I can't find any place to give the context (tried `openFileOutput` but it gets `String fileName` that can't contain path seperators). When I run my code I get this error in log cat:

```
04-11 22:13:14.899: E/error(13833): /mnt/sdcard/myTomatoes/covers/378194.PNG: open                  failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/myTomatoes/covers/378194.PNG: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at     BL.ImageMethods.SaveImageToMemory(ImageMethods.java:60)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at com.example.mytomatoes.MovieDetailsActivity$4.onClick(MovieDetailsActivity.java:337)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
04-11 22:13:14.899: W/System.err(13833):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
```

Those are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is my method for saving a file:

```
public static void SaveImageToMemory(Context context, Bitmap img, int rottenId) {
        Log.i("SAVE IMAGE", "start save");
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File location = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath()+ "/myTomatoes/covers");
        location.mkdir();
        File dest = new File(location, rottenId + ".PNG");

        try {
            Log.i("SAVE IMAGE", "trying to save: " + dest.getPath());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);

            img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

All the messed up lines for creating the `File` object are result of my try outs... The original code was:

```
    File location = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myTomatoes/covers");
    File dest = new File(location, rottenId + ".PNG");
```

I also tried to first create `ByteArrayOutputStream` and compress the Bitmap to it and then do `fos.write(mByteArrayOpStream.toByteArray())` and it didn't work.

By the way i'm using emulator but I also checked this on few "Galaxy S"s and the same error happens... (when I try to browse for the file in the phone or in DDMS I can see that it doesn't even create the folder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your problem description it seems like you couldn't even create the folder. So make sure the followings

- SD card state (mounted and writable) is good for creating folder. use this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)
- Directory is created

  if (!file.isExist())
  boolean created=file.mkdir();

later you can check if your folder is created or not by testing the Boolean value. if your folder is not created no reason to go further with your code.

- Parent folder exist.

Alternatively you can use `mkdirs()` which will create all the necessary parent directory.

Comment: thanks it helped! all I had to do was call `mkdirs()` instead of `mkdir()` and it works! Don't even need to compress the Bitmap to `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then write it I just compressed it into fos...

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
File newD = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator +"myTomatoes"+ File.separator + "covers");
   if(!newD.exists()){
        newD.mkdirs();
    }

ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    _bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

    //you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
    File f = new File( newD + File.separator + "test.jpg")
    f.createNewFile();
    //write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

    // remember close de FileOutput
    fo.close();
```

Comment: This is the log cat from this code: 
` 04-12 08:49:24.645: D/dalvikvm(29584): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5377K, 26% free 6915K/9288K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 16ms
04-12 08:49:24.654: W/System.err(29584): java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-12 08:49:24.654: W/System.err(29584):  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948) `

Answer (score 0):

just check this out :

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
        android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, filename);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    FileOutputStream f = null;
    f = new FileOutputStream(file);

    if (f != null) {
        f.write(baos.toByteArray());
        f.flush();
        f.close();
    }
}

}
```

or follow this link :http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/save-file-to-sd-card.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to store image in cache directory from android application and display that image in another activity.

**Oneactivity.java**

**storing image in the cache directory**

```
 File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "thursday.png");
                        try {
                            OutputStream output;
                            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
                            output.flush();
                            output.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

**fetching image from cache directory.**

```
BitMap bmp5;

     try {

                            File myFile = new File(getCacheDir()+"/thursday.png");
                            bmp5 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.toString());
                            System.out.println("am setting wallpaper");
                            myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bmp5);

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```